# QTableView not updating when update function called from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` along with a refresh button and some other buttons as shown below:

[image]

I have a function which refresh the table. When the refresh button is clicked the function is called. The code for  the function is given below.

```
void client_table_view::refreshTable()
{



    dbconnector db;
    QSqlQueryModel* modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(db.digi_db) ;


    qry->exec("select client_id,company_name,contact_name,address,email,phone from client_details");

    modal->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->client_table->setModel(modal);




    for (int c = 0; c < ui->client_table->horizontalHeader()->count(); ++c)
    {
        ui->client_table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(
            c, QHeaderView::Stretch);
    }
    ui->client_table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);//select the whole row instead of individual cell
    ui->client_table->setShowGrid(true);
    ui->client_table->setColumnHidden(0,true);
    qDebug()<<"Table Refreshed";
}
```

When the edit button is clicked a dialogue box appears as given below which can be used to edit any row in the table.

[image]

When save button is clicked i call the same refresh button at the end to refresh the table but it does not refresh the table. The function gets called but table don't get refreshed. The code executed when save button  clicked is given below.

```
void client_details::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{


    dbconnector db;
    QString company_name,contact_name,country,address,city,state,email,phone,website,tin;
    company_name = ui->company_name->text();
    contact_name = ui->contact_name->text();
    country = ui->countrycombobox->currentText();
    address = ui->address->toPlainText();
    city = ui->city->text();
    state = ui->state->text();
    email = ui->email->text();
    phone = ui->phone->text();
    website = ui->website->text();
    tin = ui->tin->text();
    if(window_title=="Edit Info"){

    //qDebug()<<window_title;
        db.updateClient(company_name,country,contact_name,address,city,state,email,phone,website,tin,current_client_id);

    }
    else if(window_title=="Add Client"){

    db.insertIntoClient(company_name,country,contact_name,address,city,state,email,phone,website,tin);
    }



    QMessageBox::information(
        this,
        tr("Saved"),
        tr("Information has been saved.") );


    client_table_view ctv; 
    ctv.refreshTable();   //call refresh function to refresh table view





    this->close();




}
```

Comment: Are you inserting the edited values back in the data base?

Comment: @lbarros yes. when the save button is clicked the values gets stored to database. Right after that i call refresh table function. It runs but table don't get refreshed.

Comment: If you refresh the table again, are the new values displayed correctly?

Comment: @lbarros yes they are displayed correctly. Every time i click the refresh button, the whole database refreshes. But if i call the same function from other class table doesn't get refreshed even the function get executed.

Comment: How are you calling the refresh function from other class?

Comment: @lbarros I have added the whole code for function. These are the 2 lines code for  calling the function.
    `client_table_view ctv;

   ctv.refreshTable();

Comment: It seems like your are creating a new instance of `client_table_view` and refreshing the table of that new object `ctv`, when you should be calling refresh from the original `client_table_view`. You should do that by using signals and slots.

Comment: Where is the edit window declared?

Comment: @lbarros edit window and the tableview are separate classes. Is there a way to call refresh button of tableview class when the edit window is closed.

Comment: Yes, take a look at signals and slots: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html. You will have to connect edit window's close signal, to tableview refresh method.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, your table view is not updated when inserting a new entry because you update *a new instance of the table view class*, not the one which is displayed:

```
void client_details::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ...
    client_table_view ctv; // <-- new instance here
    ctv.refreshTable();    // <-- refresh the new instance, not the one displayed!
    this->close();
}
```

In Qt, the canonical way to notify of changes is to use signal and slots:

1. define a new signal in class `client_details` to indicate an entry has been added;
2. upon adding a new client, emits the signal;
3. connect this signal to the `refreshTable()` slot in your `client_table_view`.

---

```
class client_details : public QWidget // or another widget type
{
signals:
    void entry_added();             // <-- the new signal
slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked(); // <-- see implementation below
    ...
    // the rest is as before
};

void client_details::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ...

    // instead of this:
    //     client_table_view ctv; 
    //     ctv.refreshTable();
    // just emit a signal:
    emit entry_added();

    this->close();
}

class client_table_view : public QTableView
{
slots:
    void refreshTable(); // as before
    ...
    // the rest is as before
};

// put things together, use signals/slots:
client_details * cd = new client_details(...);
client_table_view * ctv = new client_table_view(...);
connect(cd,                             // emitter
    &client_details::entry_added,       // signal
    ctv,                                // receiver
    &client_table_view::refreshTable);  // slot
```